# Moving ResultSet to first

Tags: jsp, oracle10g

I have a resultset obejct as rs and i used the fragment of code to count the number of rows..

```
       while(rs.next())
           count++;
```

and i has to use the same resultset again to retrieve the data. I used the method

```
    rs.beforefirst();
```

but it is not working... control is not entering into

```
   while(rs.next()){
      cid=rs.getInt(1);
      taskdate=rs.getString(2);
      tasktime=rs.getString(3);
      addr=rs.getString(4);
   }
```

I has to return 4 rows according to my query.. but it doesn't ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Resultset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is the forward only . If you want to navigate back to the first record you need to create **scrollable resultset** .

```
  // Create a scrollable result set
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM my_table");

// Move cursor forward
while (resultSet.next()) {
  // Get data at cursor
  String s = resultSet.getString(1);
}

// Move cursor backward
while (resultSet.previous()) {
  // Get data at cursor
  String s = resultSet.getString(1);
}

// Move cursor before first record
resultSet.beforeFirst();  //required statement in this case
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check if the `ResultSet` is of type `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` - then the call to `beforefirst` wouldn't work (according to the docs it throws in this case).](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#beforeFirst%28%29)